# Python return a linear/cumulative pairs of a list of numbers

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a pandas dataframe which has a messy concatenation of many different tables. I want to segment these tables out and perform operations on them. I have a list of table header locations that looks like this: [1, 4, 5, 7, 9, 12, 15] - so the header of the first table is at index 1, the header of the second table is at index 4, etc. My goal is to use this list to slice the dataframe and extract information from each slice and munge the data into something pretty.

I'm trying to get a list of pairs like this for this purpose: [[1,4], [4,5], [5,7], [7,9], [9,12], [12,15]]

I tried this function, but its not quite returning what I want, it returns pairs like this: 1,4, 5,7, 9,12 - this is making me skip over every other table :/.

```
def pairwise(iterable): #this is what is wrong
    a = iter(iterable)
    return izip(a, a)
```

Am I missing something? I'm going crazy here.

Comment: Why not just `[[a[x], a[x+1]] for x in range(len(a)-1)]`? assuming `a= [1, 4, 5, 7, 9, 12, 15]`

Comment: Make that the answer and I'll give you credit! This is exactly what I want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just `[[a[x], a[x+1]] for x in range(len(a)-1)]`? assuming `a= [1, 4, 5, 7, 9, 12, 15]`

Answer (score 0):

What about implementing this function like that:

```
def pairwise(itr):
    return list(zip(itr[:-1], itr[1:]))
```

So for a list `[1, 4, 5, 7, 9, 12, 15]` this function would zip `[1, 4, 5, 7, 9, 12]` and `[4, 5, 7, 9, 12, 15]`, returning the expected `[(1, 4), (4, 5), (5, 7), (7, 9), (9, 12), (12, 15)]`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to have an iterator? You can just using slicing and `zip` to get a list of the desired pairs.

```
a = [1, 4, 5, 7, 9, 12, 15]
idx_pairs = [list(z) for z in zip(a[:-1], a[1:])]
idx_pairs
>>>[[1, 4], [4, 5], [5, 7], [7, 9], [9, 12], [12, 15]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that izip is taking an item off the iterator each time, which is why the end up in pairs.  Here is a direct approach to forming the iterator:

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    seq = iter(iterable)
    a = next(seq)
    for b in seq:
        yield a,b
        a = b

list(pairwise([1,2,3,4]))
```

output:

```
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

Though if you have the lists, the following is more compact:

```
L = [1,2,3,4]
list(zip(L[:-1], L[1:]))
```

---

Cleaner iterator version, using tee and izip from itertools:

```
from itertools import tee, izip
def pairwise(iterable):
    L1, L2 = tee(iterable)
    next(L2)
    return izip(L1,L2)
```

---

Times for the three versions.  Note that the second version requires a list rather than an iterator, hence the use of the python 2.7 `range` vs `xrange`.

```
%timeit list(pairwise(xrange(1000)))
10000 loops, best of 3: 97.3 µs per loop

%timeit list(pairwise(range(1000)))
10000 loops, best of 3: 51.1 µs per loop

%timeit list(pairwise(xrange(1000)))
10000 loops, best of 3: 60.6 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you:

```
def pairwise(l1):
    l1Iter = iter(l1)
    pre = next(l1Iter)
    result = []
    for curr in l1Iter:
        result.append([pre, curr])
        pre = curr
    return result
```

Or if you don't need this list and a generator if fine:

```
def pairwise_gen(l1):
    l1Iter = iter(l1)
    pre = next(l1Iter)
    for curr in l1Iter:
       yield pre, curr
       pre = curr
```

Comment: @Leva7 is a great answer and works for everything except if a generator is passed in since generators can not handle slicing.